# Java Reactor Flux/Mono, when does doOnNext get triggered before or after element is emitted?

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have this confusion, when does doOnNext is triggered before or after of element emission by Publisher (Flux/Mono).

Comment: Since `doOnNext` provides you the element flowing through the pipeline with a `Consumer`, it is after. Order is something like this: source emits item -> doOnNext lambda is triggered -> subscriber onNext is called: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/FluxPeek.java#L167-L193

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's after the *publication* of the element - and it *has* to be after by definition, otherwise the `Consumer` passed to `doOnNext` wouldn't have access to the element emitted.

However, `doOnNext()` is called *before* the subscriber. For example:

```
Flux.just("first", "second")
        .doOnNext(x -> System.out.println(x + " onNext"))
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

...would output:

```
first onNext
first
second onNext
second
```

Comment: and doOnNext() is optional right? Is this like a hook?

Comment: @SatishPatro Correct.

Answer (score 9):

I am afraid you haven't understood reactive properly, and that's perfectly fine :). In Rx, the subscription goes bottom-up. Consider the following code:

```
Flux<Integer> f = Flux.fromIterable(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
```

Since there is no subscriber, nothing happens. No item would be emitted. Now consider this:

```
f.subscribe(System.out::println)
```

What happens is that the subscriber subscribes to the flux, and items are emitted.

Now consider this:

```
f.doOnNext(System.out::println).subscribe(System.out.println);
```

Remember, the subscription happens in a bottom-up manner. So over here, the subscriber subscribes to the `doOnNext()`, and the `doOnNext()` subscribes to the original flux, which then starts emitting events. `doOnNext()` then intercepts each event and performs some side-effect.

Comment: Prashant, I admit that I am still trying to get my head around the reactive stuff. Though the question from a requirement where I need to execute something just before publisher starts working to produce data.