# How do understand r2dbc save

Tags: spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

i want konw r2dbc principle, so i debug the code, but i find it work weird.

```
        Flux.range(1, 10)
                .flatMap(id -> repository.save(new Student(id, "lxp")))
                .doOnNext(System.out::println)
                .subscribe();
```

why it run all `save` before run doOnNext?
In my understanding, it run save then doOnNext one by one.

it hard.hope someone can help me.thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is partially here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57208219/182393

In addition, `flatMap` is emitting events (saves) in an asynchronous way. So, you have `range` of events, that are handled in `flatMap` asynchronously (all at the same time) and then they go to `doOnNext`, and finally to `subscribe`.

Your code is not sequential (and this is why reactive programming causes madness).

Comment: so do you know how to measure the time spent on individual elements? like the time taken by the number 1. I try to use Flux#tap,but i think it is asynchronous way.

Comment: Personally, I will extract this lambda to another method and add some aspect around just to log time. Messy, but easy (if you use Spring or know how to use AspectJ).